# Updating a single item in mongoDB whilst keeping the rest the same

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

I am using a mongoDB where each object (I think of this as a row) has about 30 items (I think of the items as columns), I want to use an update function so that just a single item in each object is updated when its called whilst keeping the rest the same. Below is the code I am using.

```
    const handleTeamUpdate = (id, column, value) => {
        const obj = {
            [column]: value
        };
        axios
            .post('http://localhost:4000/todos/update/' + id, obj)
            .then(() => {
                console.log(`Team updated`)
                fetchTeams() // refresh the teams
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(`There was an error updating.`))
    }
```

```
todoRoutes.route('/update/:id').post(function (req, res) {
    Todo.findById(req.params.id, function (err, todo) {
        if (!todo)
            res.status(404).send("data is not found");
        else
             todo.Team_Name = req.body.Team_Name;
             todo.Team_Manager = req.body.Team_Manager;
             todo.Department = req.body.Department;
             todo.Location = req.body.Location;
           // 26 more columns below the above

                todo.save().then(todo => {
                    res.json('Todo updated!');
                })
                    .catch(err => {
                        res.status(400).send("Update not possible");
                    });
    });
});
```

What my current code seems to do is update the item I specify (I refer to this as column in my code) but then seems to delete/nullify every other 'column' - I am looking for a solution which updates the column I specify but also keeps every other column the same - I would prefer if I don't have to state each column as an argument in my Update function as it will make the code much more messy.

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of POST**

1. Use **PUT** when you want to modify a singular resource that is already a part of resource collection.
2. Use **PATCH** if request updates part of the resource.

Comment: Tried both Put and Patch and neither gives the desired result, Put gives me the same outcome and patch doesn't update at all

Answer (score 0):

If not using Mongoose [middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) or [validations](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) on the `Todo` model schema. Its better to use `update()` or `updateMany()` or `findByIdAndUpdate()` which essentially delegates the whole query to mongo server.

Example with [`findByIdAndUpdate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) :

```
const updateObject = {
  Team_Name: req.body.Team_Name,
  Team_Manager: req.body.Team_Manager,
  Department: req.body.Department,
  Location: req.body.Location,
};

//if the properties in req.body are same as the fields to be update use spread syntax below
// const updateObject = {...req.body};
Todo.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, updateObject, { new: true }, function (
  err,
  todo
) {
  if (err) {
    console.error("error occured!", err);
    return;
  }

  console.info("Updated object is::", todo);
});
```